# Copy one csv header to another csv with type modification

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to copy one csv header to another in row wise with some modifications

Input csv

```
name,"Mobile Number","mobile1,mobile2",email2,Address,email21
test, 123456789,+123456767676,a@test.com,testaddr,a1@test.com
test1,7867778,8799787899898,b@test,com, test2addr,b2@test.com
```

In new csv this should be like this and file should also be created. And for sting column I will pass the column name so only that column will be converted to string

```
name.auto()
Mobile Number.auto()
mobile1,mobile2.string()
email2.auto()
Address.auto()
email21.auto()
```

As you see above all these header with type modification should be inserted in different rows

I have tried with below command but this is only for copy first row

```
sed '1!d' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Tushar I have updated the question with my effort.

Comment: @user13000875 - I am not able to understand the output requirement. Do you want to split the header row into multiple lines?

Comment: What is the criterion for using `.string()`?

Comment: @Tushar I want to split header into multiple lines with type added modifications

Comment: So you want to print the first line modified and discard all other lines from the input, right? You say `I will pass the column name` - show in your question exactly how you want to do that, e.g. `script "mobile1,mobile2"` or `script 3` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this alternative `gnu awk` command as well:

```sh
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' 'NR == 1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      print gensub(/"/, "", "g", $i) "." ($i ~ /,/ ? "string" : "auto") "()"
   exit
}' file
```

```
name.auto()
Mobile Number.auto()
mobile1,mobile2.string()
email2.auto()
Address.auto()
email21.auto()
```

---

Or using `sed`:

```sh
sed -i -e '1i 1234567890.string(),My address is test.auto(),abc3@gmail.com.auto(),120000003.auto(),abc-003.auto(),3.com.auto()' -e '1d' test.csv
```

Comment: You solution prints perfect but when I save this output to a file then mobile1 is saving in one column and mobile2.string() is on another column

Comment: Do you have some DOS line endings in your input file? Can you show output of `head file | cat -A` command?

Comment: name,"Mobile Number","mobile1,mobile2",email2,Address,email21$. After running head file | cat -A command

Comment: ok then run `awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print gensub(/"/, "", "g", $i) "." ($i ~ /,/ ? "string()" : "auto()"); exit}' file > out; cat -A out`

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment to print only first line(header) please try following.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^".*,.*"$/){
      gsub(/"/,"",$i)
      print $i".string()"
    }
    else{
      print $i".auto()"
    }
  }
  exit
}
' Input_file > output_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with GUN `awk` with shown samples.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^".*,.*"$/){
      gsub(/"/,"",$i)
      print $i".string()"
    }
    else{
      print $i".auto()"
    }
  }
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '  ##Starting awk program and setting FPAT to [^,]*|"[^"]+".
FNR==1{                        ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){          ##Running for loop from i=1 to till NF value.
    if($i~/^".*,.*"$/){        ##Checking condition if current field starts from " and ends with " and having comma in between its value then do following.
      gsub(/"/,"",$i)          ##Substitute all occurrences of " with NULL in current field.
      print $i".string()"      ##Printing current field and .string() here.
    }
    else{                      ##else do following.
      print $i".auto()"        ##Printing current field dot auto() string here.
    }
  }
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                              ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I only want to this for header.

Comment: @user13000875, ok sure, edited the answer now, it will edit the very first line and print the rest of the lines as it is, let me know.

Comment: Rest of the lines I don't wan to print into new file . only headers need to print

Comment: @user13000875, Please try my EDIT solution once and let me know then?

Comment: @your solution works when there is no space and comma in header column . but when space or comma in headers column then all the data is printing in single line

Comment: @user13000875, solutions will be always given s per shown samples only, your samples are not having something like this, kindly don't change your very starting question, that is not encouraged on SO, you could see if this solution works for you and for other questions you could open a separate question then.